# Print line numbers on MonoMac application stack traces

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, mono, monomac

I have a MonoMac application and would like to see what line caused the exception. All my stack traces are like this:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: I am going to crash now.
  atSync.MacConfiguration..ctor (System.String destinationPath, IDatabasePathGenerator pathGenerator) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Sync.MacConfiguration..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <0x001f3>
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <0x00024>
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (object[]) <0x00042>
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,bool) <0x001d3>
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type) <0x00013>
at Sync.ConfigurationSection.get_Configuration () <0x00043>
at Sync.Configuration.LoadFromXML (string) <0x000cf>
at Sync.Configuration.get_Default () <0x0005f>
at Sync.Mac.AppDelegate..ctor () <0x00037>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.905edfe4-e0b5-4f92-955e-4e10c991fb3a (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector) <0x00057>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.905edfe4-e0b5-4f92-955e-4e10c991fb3a (intptr,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector) <0x0006f>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[]) <0x00003>
at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) <0x0003f>
at Sync.Mac.MainClass.Main (string[]) <0x000e7>
```

I have tried copying the `.mdb` files to the `Contents/MonoBundle` folder, but I still don't see line numbers on my stack traces.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, to see line numbers you not only need the .mdb, but also to call mono with the flag "--debug".

Now, on Mac I'm not sure if this works (or if it's even possible because you're using a bundle and I'm not sure if that means you get all compiled into one single executable?).

Comment: Tried to use the `MONO_ENV_OPTIONS` variable with `--debug` but still didn't work.